# R Tidy_text: Count String Patterns, not Words

Tags: r, tidytext

I am looking  to count the occurrence of blog tags in a vector (column). Here is the column:

```
> head(df$tags)
[1] "blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / "    "election / WA / blog / voting system / "                      
[3] "blog / "  "euthanasia / media / Labor / Qld / assisted suicide / "       
[5] "abortion / SA / blog / abortion-to-birth / "                   
[6] "euthanasia / media / Tas / assisted suicide / mike gaffney / "
```

`/'tag'/` is the format. I can use tidy_text to count the words with the following code:

```
wordCount <- df %>%  
  unnest_tokens(word, tags) %>% 
  anti_join(stop_words) %>% 
  count(word, sort = TRUE)
```

However, this obviously breaks up the tags and just counts the words. I need to count the occurrence of the tags themselves, and not the individual words.

I actually have no idea where to start with this one, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `euthanasia` also a tag, despite that it be surrounded by `/` only on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tokenize using a regular expression in [tidytext](/questions/tagged/tidytext), which may be what you're looking for:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

df <- tibble(tags = c("blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / ",
                      "election / WA / blog / voting system / ",
                      "blog / ",
                      "euthanasia / media / Labor / Qld / assisted suicide / ",
                      "abortion / SA / blog / abortion-to-birth / ",
                      "euthanasia / media / Tas / assisted suicide / mike gaffney / "))

df %>%
  unnest_tokens(tag, tags, token = "regex", pattern = "\\s*\\/\\s*")
#> # A tibble: 23 x 1
#>    tag          
#>    <chr>        
#>  1 blog         
#>  2 thank you    
#>  3 nsw          
#>  4 ndoa         
#>  5 election     
#>  6 wa           
#>  7 blog         
#>  8 voting system
#>  9 blog         
#> 10 euthanasia   
#> # … with 13 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Julia, solution was great. Also, great website.

Answer (score 0):

It's doable with a simple strsplit

```r
df %>% 
    mutate( word = strsplit( gdata::trim(tags), "\\s*\\/\\s*" ) ) %>%
    unnest( cols=word )
```

I get this:

```
> df
                                                           tags
1                              blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / 
2                       election / WA / blog / voting system / 
3                                                       blog / 
4        euthanasia / media / Labor / Qld / assisted suicide / 
5                   abortion / SA / blog / abortion-to-birth / 
6 euthanasia / media / Tas / assisted suicide / mike gaffney / 
> df %>% 
+     mutate( word = strsplit( gdata::trim(tags), "\\s*\\/\\s*" ) ) %>%
+     unnest( cols=word )
# A tibble: 23 x 2
   tags                                                     word    
   <chr>                                                    <chr>        
 1 "blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / "                       blog         
 2 "blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / "                       thank you    
 3 "blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / "                       NSW          
 4 "blog / thank you / NSW / ndoa / "                       ndoa         
 5 "election / WA / blog / voting system / "                election     
 6 "election / WA / blog / voting system / "                WA           
 7 "election / WA / blog / voting system / "                blog         
 8 "election / WA / blog / voting system / "                voting system
 9 "blog / "                                                blog         
10 "euthanasia / media / Labor / Qld / assisted suicide / " euthanasia   
# … with 13 more rows
>
```

This you can probably tie in with the rest of your data flow.